# Custom kernel module Integration

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

I have been asked to integrate a custom JPEG encoder kernel module to the linux tree. The description is too generic. Can anyone suggest where in kernel tree should this go? I mean under what category in the drivers? I am assuming this is going to be compiled as a module and not statically linked to the kernel. If I generalize the question where should any custom kernel module live in the kernel tree? Assume the kernel module is a video/audio decoder/encoder. In this case it is a JPEG encoder as I said.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Is it driver for hardware which encodes, or purely software solution?

Comment: Yes there is a dedicated hw block which does the actual encoding.

Comment: Consider *drivers/media* folder. It should be v4l2 compatible driver if you want to get it integrated nicely.

Comment: This may sound bit stupid but pardon me asking, can a driver sit inside the kernel tree e.g. inside driver/media but still be compiled as a kernel module? Or it has to be statically linked to the kernel.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22929065/difference-between-linux-loadable-and-built-in-modules

Comment: @0andriy Thanks. As the driver it came from a "third party" I had to put the driver outside the kernel in a folder "third party" and compile it out of kernel as a module.   This brings me to the second problem of specifying the KDIR path in the module Makefile. For the time being I have hard coded the KDIR path in the makefile as:  KDIR ?= /home/vivekb/repos/src/buildroot/output/build/linux-custom.   I am invoking the make from a bash script:  make ARCH=mips CROSS_COMPILE=mips-img-linux-gnu- CONFIG_xyz=y. This works. But if I try invoking the make KDIR=<<path>> it doesn't work.

Comment: You need to run `make -C <KERNEL_BUILD> M=$PWD modules`.in the folder of module you are compiling. `KERNEL_BUILD` refers to a folder where kernel has been built (sometimes it's the same as `KERNEL_SRC` — kernel sources).

Answer (score 0):

When I posted this question I did not have clarity as how drivers are categorized and placed in the kernel tree. So explored and this is what I found so far:

1. If I am integrating/writing a new driver e.g. Ring Oscillator (this device simply generates some frequencies given a input period value, the frequency number is fed to a random number generator). To my understanding this should go under linux/drivers/misc/ whereas someone argued this should go under linux/drivers/misc/. But apart from that there seems to no strict rule where this kind of drivers should go. So it is quite up to your discretion and judgment where you ultimately place it. I have given the details of the steps involved [here](https://vivekbhadra.wordpress.com/2017/07/19/how-to-integrate-a-custom-device-driver-into-kernel-tree/).
2. I also had to integrate a jpeg encoder and I was confused where this driver should go. I initially thought I will place it under linux/drivers/media/ as suggested in the comments. But this turned out to be a matter of preference. Finally I integrated it as a new buildroot package. In case you are interested I have described it [here](https://vivekbhadra.wordpress.com/2017/06/15/how-to-addcompile-a-kernel-module-as-a-new-buildroot-package/).

This is my understanding so far. If anyone thinks if I have missed anything please kindly point out.

Comment: i don't understand what you are trying to say ?

Comment: I am not sure sure which part you didn't get the question or the answer? I can clarify if there is any specific point you didn't understand.

Comment: it's broad answer if i am not wrong.Please try to explain with examples or codes @EmbeddedDev

Comment: When you are working on a specific product your software tree would have a Kernel repository along with other repositories. So if you are given a custom driver to be integrated in the tree how do you go about it? Where do you place it in the tree? Do you necessarily have to place it somewhere under the "linux/driver" folder? Do you statically link it to the kernel?

Comment: @RohitPoudel Ok I got your point and will explain with codes snippets.

Comment: @RohitPoudel btw in case of the jpeg encoder, the details are already given in the link. For the ring oscillator. I will add more codes.

Comment: that's fine. it will be easier for others too

Comment: 1. I think it closer to where clock providers are located (basically *drivers/clk/*. 2. Yes, *drivers/media/platform/* for example. If in doubt, ask in public mailing lists. LKML as a good start for asking some help.

Comment: @0andriy that's a very good point, I have recently subscribed to the LKML, thanks for pointing out.